# Adding Var to jQuery.getScript() url string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I included Var with url string to JS files directory in my PHP page:

```
var jsDir= "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js";
```

Now I need to add each JS files within .js file using `jQuery.getScript` and I need help adding the directory var `jsDir` to the url string:

```
$.getScript( "/plugin.js");
```

Comment: Note that wordpress have ways to enqueue scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty trivial string concatenation

```
$.getScript( jsDir + "/plugin.js");
```